# Magento 2 Get admin user collection with specific role name

Tags: magento2, admin, custom-grid

I have a custom module which has all the admin users listed. Now I want to list admin users with specific roles.

In my grid collection code it has below code which get all the users:

```
$collection = $this->_userFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $table = $collection->getTable('authorization_role');

    $collection->getSelect()
    ->join(['role' => $table], 'main_table.user_id=role.user_id');
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('role.role_name', ['nin' => ['Administrators', 'XYZ']]);

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    parent::_prepareCollection();

    return $this;
```

I want to show all users which do not have these 2 roles "Administrator, XYZ".

How could I make join in the collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution as below:

```php
    use  Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\CollectionFactory as UserCollectionFactory;

    /**
    * @var \Arrow\Customerassignment\Model\userFactory
    */
    protected $_userFactory;

    public function __construct(UserCollectionFactory $userFactory)
    {
        $this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $adminUsers = $this->_userFactory->create();

        $excludedUsersId = [];

        foreach($adminUsers as $adminUser) {
            if(in_array($adminUser->getRole()->getRoleName(), ['Administrators', 'XYZ'])) {
                $excludedUsersId[] = $adminUser->getId();
            }
        }

        $collection = $adminUsers->addFieldToFilter('main_table.user_id', ['nin' => $excludedUsersId]);

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will join role table with user table and gives you both table data and filter based on role name.

```
    $collection = $this->_userFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $table = $collection->getTable('authorization_role');
    $connection = $collection->getConnection();
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(['role' => $table], 'main_table.user_id=role.user_id');
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('role.role_name', ['nin' => ['Administrators', 'admin']]);`
```

**UPDATE**

```
    $collection = $this->_userFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $table = $collection->getTable('authorization_role');
    $connection = $collection->getConnection();
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(['role' => $table], 'main_table.user_id=role.user_id', ['role_user_id' => 'role.user_id']);
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('role.role_name', ['nin' => ['Administrators', 'admin']]);
```

Comment: showing error below:

2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in order clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `role`.* FROM `admin_user` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `authorization_role` AS `role` ON main_table.user_id=role.user_id WHERE (`role`.`role_name` NOT IN('Administrators', 'RegionalManager')) ORDER BY user_id DESC
 LIMIT 20

Comment: update your full code.

Comment: question updated please check and let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: try updated answer

Comment: it showing all the user,  join condition not working. :(

Comment: Update your whole file because I have checked this code and it will give me perfect output

Comment: it threw error `Zend_Db_Select_Exception with message 'You cannot define a correlation name 'role' more than once'`

Answer (score 0):

I just send you the example of join query

You can see the code and try to make it your own query using this format.

```
$collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');

$collection->getSelect()->join(
array('value_entity' => $collection->getTable('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value')),
'e.entity_id = value_entity.entity_id',
array('value_id'));


$collection->getSelect()
->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
->columns('entity_id')        
->group(array('entity_id'));

echo '<pre>';print_r($collection->getData());die('died');
```